# Executing remote bash script over ssh in a loop

Tags: bash, loops, ssh, stdin

The problem that I have is very specific:

I have a script that goes through a list of servers indefinitely, and executes a copy of itself (with specific set of arguments) on each one. Remote script `stdout` should be captured, as well as the time spent executing it. Here is a very simplified example:

```
export TIMEFORMAT="%0E seconds"
server1=localhost
index=1

if [ "$1" != "" ]
then
 cd /home
 mv -n test _test &>/dev/null
 sleep 10
 echo $1
 mv -n _test test &>/dev/null
else
 i=0
 while [ $i -lt $index ]
 do
  ((i++))
  server="server$i"
  time=/tmp/time
  echo "${!server} is doing stuff..."
  result=$((time ssh ${!server} "$(basename $0) argument" 2>/dev/null </dev/null) 2>$time)
  echo "Done in $(<$time), the result is $result"
  rm $time
 done
fi
```

So, if the script received an argument, it executes itself locally (as an example, renames a file and does nothing for 10 seconds); otherwise, it loops through a list of servers (as an example, there is only one server in the list) and call itself on a remote host. `2>$time` captures the `time`'s stderr to a file, `2>/dev/null` keeps it quiet on errors and `</dev/null` prevents `ssh` from stealing `stdin`, so it can safely run in a loop.

The problem is, when user terminates the script with `ctrl+c`, the copy of the script SHOULD still terminate gracefully on a remote host (i.e. the file is renamed to the initial name), but it does not. Doing the same thing without loop works fine - user terminates the script, remote copy is still running and ends gracefully, user just doesn't get to see the output, which is quite fine. My theory is that the problem has something to do with `ssh` being in a loop and `</dev/null` preventing it to steal the `stdin`, but I cannot think of a way to bypass this. Any suggestion is greatly  appreciated.

Comment: Does running the script on remote under `nohup` change the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

user2303197's suggestion makes perfect sense - make the remote script immune to hangup signal, but unfortunately, it doesn't affect the behavior of the script. But the suggestion inspired me to do the exact opposite - `nohup` the ssh call, like this:

```
result=$((time nohup ssh ${!server} "$(basename $0) argument" & 2>/dev/null </dev/null) 2>$time)
```

It makes the ssh immune to `ctrl+c`, but it breaks the loop in which it is running as soon as it's done, and that is exactly what I need it to do.

EDIT:
After a week of testing, it turns out that this script does not perform as I wanted to. When the connection to the remote host is dropped, the remote script does not end gracefully. Any suggestions how to fix this?